# Unity WebGL Progress bar never moves but game finishes downloading and works

Tags: unity, webgl

Not sure why but the progress bar never moves for WebGL in Chrome, but the game downloads and works?

Using Unity 2020.1.14f1 brotli WebGL builds

Comment: Sounds like a bug to report to the Unity developers, not a problem with your game that we can help you with.

Answer (score 0):

This is just guesswork as I'm still searching for the answer to this myself but I seem to remember that it may be a server misconfiguration causing the loader to fall back onto a non-compressed load. Somehow I think this stops the loader from having access to how much data has downloaded so far.

Answer (score 0):

I found this was fixed on 2021.2.X, is a known issue, https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/webgl-incorrect-loading-progress-is-shown-in-the-player-when-build-files-are-compressed-using-brotli